# Can I get the Cuba tourist card from Aeroflot or at Havana?

Tags: visas, paperwork, cuba, aeroflot

Can I get the Cuba tourist card when boarding Aeroflot from Moscow?

I'm an Indian citizen travelling from Delhi-Moscow-Cuba.

Comment: You can get it in Havana, but many airlines (perhaps Aeroflot?) won't let you board without it.

Comment: What if i book ticket on cuban national airlines??

Comment: No idea, that's why I put it as a comment, not an answer. I know you can get it on arrival in Havana, but some airlines require it before boarding. However, I don't know which do and which don't.

Comment: Yes I can understand but here I not getting confirmed clarirification from aeroflot as well as from the embassy.

Answer (score 2):

### The Airline Might Not Provide the Tourist Card

I tried searching the web for information on this topic. Turns out I could not find a one unique truth. According to the [Cuba tripadvisor traveler article](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g147270-c104245/Cuba:Caribbean:Tourist.Card.Visa.html) it seems that selected tour operators provide the Tourist Card as part of their package. However, it would also seem that **the release of tourist cards from airlines depends from the country of departure**. Airlines flying from Canada for example should provide them, whereas [this seems not to be the case when departing from Europe](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/permalink/post/20925332). Regarding India in particular, I found a [tripadvisor discussion](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k7916826-o10-Cuba_Tourist_card_on_Aeroflot-Air_Travel.html) which mentions a cryptic procedure to be completed with the Cuban embassy in Delhi. Moreover, [the Aeroflot website mentions nothing specific to Cuba](http://www.aeroflot.com/cms/en/before_and_after_fly/custom_rules). So ultimately I would advise you to contact the airline and ask.

It is worthy to note that some airlines will not allow you to board without a Tourist Card. Once again, [the Aeroflot website does not specify this](http://www.aeroflot.com/cms/en/before_and_after_fly/custom_rules). So I would avoid trying your luck by attempting to fly without obtaining a Tourist Card first.

### Apply with the Cuban Embassy

If I were you, and I had the time, I would apply to the Cuban embassy in Delhi. Quoting from [their site](http://www.cubadiplomatica.cu/india/EN/ConsularServices.aspx#TouristCard):

> **Tourist Visa (Tourist Card)**
>
> The Tourist Visa or Tourist Card is only for purposes of tourism to
>   Cuba.  It is valid for one single entrance into national territory for
>   a 30-day trip and can be extended for an additional 30 days at the
>   office in the hotel where one has accommodations or with the
>   immigration authority.
>
> Minors must have their own Tourist Card even if they are travelling
>   under their parents’ passport(s).
>
> To obtain this visa in person at the Consulate, these documents are
>   needed:
>
> - Valid Passport
> - Plane Ticket with entry and return dates
> - Payment of the Consular fee for this service
>
> These documents are needed to obtain this visa by mail:
>
> - Legible photocopy of valid Passport
> - Legible photocopy of plane ticket with entry and return dates
> - Payment of the Consular fee for this service
> - Stamped self-addressed envelope for the visa to be sent back
>
> NOTE: If the application is made by mail or via a third party, an
>   extra consular fee will be charged for the pertinent Consular service.
>
> All payments must be made in cash or by a bank certified cheque.  All
>   cash sent by mail will be refused and returned at the risk of the
>   applicant.

The visa’s fee is 4400 INR, excluding extra services such as express application and postage handling. You can find some complimentary information on [this document](http://www.cubadiplomatica.cu/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=52kAMSgavzE%3D&tabid=20393), and [the application form here](http://www.cubadiplomatica.cu/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=0AQTojgyFqo%3D&tabid=20393).